# Passing data from service to parent then from parent to child component

Tags: angular, typescript

Okay, guys, I am new to Angular and I have a problem and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My parent component looks like this and I am trying to pass the **weekly** variable to my child component:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { GeolocationService } from "./geolocation.service";
import { WeatherService } from "./weather.service";
import { kmphToMs } from '../utilities/helpful';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  cityName: string;
  currentTemp: number;
  currentHumidity: number;
  currentWindSpeed: string;
  weekly: Array<object>;
  erroMessage: string;

  constructor(
    private geolocationService: GeolocationService,
    private weatherService: WeatherService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.geolocationService.getCoordinates().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.latitude = result.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = result.coords.longitude;
      this.weatherService
        .getTheWeather(this.latitude, this.longitude)
        .subscribe(weatherData => {
          console.log(weatherData);
          this.cityName = weatherData["timezone"];
          this.currentTemp = weatherData["currently"]["temperature"];
          this.currentWindSpeed = kmphToMs(weatherData["currently"]["windSpeed"]);
          this.currentHumidity = weatherData['currently']['humidity'] * 100;
          this.weekly = weatherData['daily']['data'];
          console.table(this.weekly);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <app-days
    [weekly]="weekly"
  ></app-days>
```

And this is what my child component looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-days",
  templateUrl: "./days.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./days.component.css"]
})
export class DaysComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() weekly: Array<object>;


  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.weekly); 
  }
}
```

I'm trying to **console.log** the weekly variable but it says it is undefined and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AppComponent`'s template will start loading before your Subscription gets completed. And till then the `weekly` variable will be undefined on the `AppComponent`.

Try reading it in `ngOnChanges`. That's what gets called every time an `@Input` property is changed on a Component. So as soon as `weekly` gets initialized in the AppComponent, `ngOnChanges` will get called with the updated `weekly` value.

```
import { Component, OnChanges, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-days",
  templateUrl: "./days.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./days.component.css"]
})
export class DaysComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() weekly: Array<object>;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.weekly); 
  }

}
```

To prevent `undefined` value, you can place an `*ngIf` in your `AppComponent`'s template:

```
<app-days *ngIf="weekly" [weekly]="weekly" ></app-days>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your GEO service is setting the weekly variable asynchronously. So by the time the child components' ngOnInit method is invoked the async call in the parent has likely not finished.

Add {{weekly|json}} in your child template html to debug if the data gets set.

Answer (score 1):

The reason being the weekly is undefined in AppComponent initially and is populated from the result geolocationService.getCoordinates() asynchronously.

However, in DaysComponent you are trying to refer the weekly data on ngOnInit hook, which does not guarantee that this service call will have completed.

Below are the few suggestions that you can do:

1. Add an ngIf directive to app-days based on existence of weekly. or,
2. Implement OnChanges in DaysComponent and continue your work when
   input weekly is changed., or
3. You can announce the change via Subject/Observable and listen for change in your component and react accordingly.

Comment: Which one is the best practice?

Comment: Prevent rendering of the child component until weekly is defined using `*ngIf`. The other two options are not really required and would increase the complexity of your App without adding any value.